# SCUI.h file not found error in SoundCloud

Tags: ios

I have used the **soundcloud sdk documentation** provided here:

```
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart#installation
```

but i always come up with the error SCUI.h not found.

Comment: even if you add the .h file directly to the list of files in the left side of your Xcode project?

Comment: After adding SCUI.h directly then its giving error for #import "SCAPI.h" file not found.